# Get specific series values in order

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, analytic-functions

I have a table contains the info of the access time and movements for each employee.

Some employees have shift work hours between two days, I have column determine if this access time belongs to the previous or current day.

I need to collect the access time which belongs to one day, then get the difference between the current access time and the next one and determine the check status of the movement(first or last or during the day movement).

I get the mentioned result if the employee has shift work hours on the same day but I can't get the true result if he has work hours between two days.

**Example:**

Employee Number 1 has Shift method: 17:00 -> 01:00

Employee Number 2 has Shift method: 08:30 -> 16:30

Total Work Hours: 08:00

```
   CREATE TABLE My_Table (
  EMP_ID    NUMBER(4) ,
  Timeinout date ,
  flag number(1)
 
);

INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('03-07-2018 16:39:44','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('04-07-2018 01:14:40','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('04-07-2018 01:14:44 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('04-07-2018 16:14:52','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('05-07-2018 01:07:40','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('05-07-2018 01:07:44 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('05-07-2018 16:31:08','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('06-07-2018 01:01:48 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (1,to_date('06-07-2018 01:01:52','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),1);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('03-07-2018 08:37:40','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('03-07-2018 16:27:36','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('04-07-2018 08:37:04 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('04-07-2018 12:58:36','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('04-07-2018 13:09:48 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);
INSERT INTO My_Table VALUES (2,to_date('04-07-2018 17:15:32 ','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),0);


COMMIT;
```

The query I used is for employee number2 return the true result:

```
   select X.*,
       CASE
         WHEN Previous_Movment IS NULL AND Next_Movment IS NOT NULL THEN
          'First Check'
         WHEN Previous_Movment IS NOT NULL AND Next_Movment IS NULL THEN
          'Last Check'
         when Previous_Movment IS NULL AND Next_Movment IS NULL THEN
          'Do Not have access in this day'
         ELSE
          'During the Day'
       end CHECK_sTATUS
  from (select trunc(a.timeinout) as date_,
               a.timeinout current_movment,
               LEAD(TIMEINOUT) OVER(partition by trunc(TIMEINOUT), Emp_ID ORDER BY TIMEINOUT, Emp_ID) Next_Movment,
               LAG(TIMEINOUT) OVER(partition by trunc(TIMEINOUT), Emp_ID ORDER BY TIMEINOUT, Emp_ID) Previous_Movment,
               trunc(24 *
                     mod(LEAD(TIMEINOUT) OVER(partition by trunc(TIMEINOUT),
                              Emp_ID ORDER BY TIMEINOUT,
                              Emp_ID) - TIMEINOUT,
                         1)) as diff_hours,
               trunc(mod(mod(LEAD(TIMEINOUT)
                             OVER(partition by trunc(TIMEINOUT),
                                  Emp_ID ORDER BY TIMEINOUT,
                                  Emp_ID) - TIMEINOUT,
                             1) * 24,
                         1) * 60) as diff_minus,
               trunc(mod(mod(mod(LEAD(TIMEINOUT)
                                 OVER(partition by trunc(TIMEINOUT),
                                      Emp_ID ORDER BY TIMEINOUT,
                                      Emp_ID) - TIMEINOUT,
                                 1) * 24,
                             1) * 60,
                         1) * 60) as diff_sec,
               Emp_ID,
               FLAG Return_Previous_day_or_not
          from My_table a
         WHERE trunc(a.timeinout) between
               to_Date('03-07-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy') and
               to_Date('07-07-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
          and a.Emp_ID = 2
        
        ) X
```

and the get the below result for employee number2:

[image]

But when I switch the query to employee number1 I get the wrong result because the movements between two days:

[image]
**Note:**

I used ***Trunc(Timeinout)*** in the **LEAD & lAG** function for the employee who has work hours on the same day.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for a minimal example of your data; the `INSERT` statements for your sample data (both as text and not images, which we cannot copy/paste from); the expected output for your sample data; and an English (not code) explanation of the logic of how to get from your sample data to the expected output. If you just provide your output as images then we have to try to reverse engineer your tables and data; this makes it a high bar to be able to answer the question so provide everything to help us to help you.

Comment: @MT0 thank you, I edited the question and hope your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MODEL` clause:

```sql
SELECT emp_id,
       current_movement,
       flag,
       previous_movement,
       next_movement,
       (next_movement - current_movement) DAY TO SECOND AS diff,
       check_status
FROM   (
  SELECT m.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout) AS rn
  FROM   my_table m
)
MODEL
  PARTITION BY (emp_id)
  DIMENSION BY (rn)
  MEASURES (
    timeinout AS current_movement,
    flag,
    CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS first_movement,
    CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS previous_movement,
    CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS next_movement,
    CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(11)) AS check_status
  )
  RULES (
    first_movement[1]       = current_movement[1],
    first_movement[rn>1]    = CASE
                              WHEN current_movement[cv(rn)] < first_movement[cv(rn)-1] + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
                              THEN first_movement[cv(rn)-1]
                              ELSE current_movement[cv(rn)]
                              END,
    previous_movement[1]    = NULL,
    previous_movement[rn>1] = CASE
                              WHEN current_movement[cv(rn)] < first_movement[cv(rn)-1] + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
                              THEN current_movement[cv(rn)-1]
                              ELSE NULL
                              END,
    next_movement[1]        = current_movement[cv(rn)+1],
    next_movement[rn>1]     = CASE
                              WHEN current_movement[cv(rn)+1] < first_movement[cv(rn)] + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
                              THEN current_movement[cv(rn)+1]
                              ELSE NULL
                              END,
    check_status[1]         = 'FIRST_CHECK',
    check_status[rn>1]      = CASE
                              WHEN first_movement[cv(rn)-1] != first_movement[cv(rn)]
                              THEN 'FIRST_CHECK'
                              WHEN current_movement[cv(rn)+1] < first_movement[cv(rn)] + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
                              THEN 'DURING_DAY'
                              ELSE 'LAST_CHECK'
                              END
  )
```

Which outputs:

> | EMP_ID | CURRENT_MOVEMENT | FLAG | PREVIOUS_MOVEMENT | NEXT_MOVEMENT | DIFF | CHECK_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | 0 |  | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 | +00 08:34:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 | 1 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | 0 |  | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 | +00 08:52:48.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 | 1 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | 0 |  | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 | +00 08:30:40.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 | 1 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 | 0 |  | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 | +00 07:49:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 | 0 | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | 0 |  | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | +00 04:21:32.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | 0 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | +00 00:11:12.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | 0 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | +00 04:05:44.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | 0 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=106ab96a696ada1efd6d04fe75da3374)*

Comment: @MTO thank you man, you give me a lot of rich info and examples

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for this.

Assuming that you want a shift to last for no more than 12 hours (yours appear to be 8 hours and people check in early and leave later) then:

```sql
SELECT emp_id,
       timeinout AS current_movement,
       flag,
       CASE
       WHEN cls IN ('FIRST_CHECK', 'DURING_DAY')
       THEN next_timeinout
       END AS next_movement,
       CASE
       WHEN cls IN ('DURING_DAY', 'LAST_CHECK')
       THEN prev_timeinout
       END AS previous_movement,
       CASE
       WHEN cls IN ('FIRST_CHECK', 'DURING_DAY')
       THEN (next_timeinout - timeinout) DAY TO SECOND
       END AS diff,
       cls AS check_status
FROM   my_table
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  PARTITION BY emp_id
  ORDER BY timeinout
  MEASURES
    PREV(timeinout) AS prev_timeinout,
    NEXT(timeinout) AS next_timeinout,
    LAST(last_check.timeinout) AS last_timeinout,
    CLASSIFIER() AS cls
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (first_check (during_day* last_check)?)
  DEFINE
    during_day AS timeinout < first_check.timeinout + INTERVAL '12' HOUR,
    last_check AS timeinout < first_check.timeinout + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
) m
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | EMP_ID | CURRENT_MOVEMENT | FLAG | NEXT_MOVEMENT | PREVIOUS_MOVEMENT | DIFF | CHECK_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | 0 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 |  | +00 08:34:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | 1 |  | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | 0 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 |  | +00 08:52:48.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | 1 |  | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | 0 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 |  | +00 08:30:40.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | 1 |  | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 | 0 | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 |  | +00 07:49:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 | 0 |  | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | 0 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 |  | +00 04:21:32.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | 0 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | +00 00:11:12.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | 0 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | +00 04:05:44.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | 0 |  | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 |  | LAST_CHECK |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ccb269d78ab9ec4ea31a395c7669d120)*

Comment: @MTO, Sorry I forget to mention it, I'm using Oracle 10g.

Comment: _" I'm using Oracle 10g"_   10.2 went out of extended support Jul 2013 - over eight years ago.

Comment: @EdStevens I know that, but the system I work on them used exclusive Oracle 10 or oracle 11

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 11gR2, you can use a recursive sub-query:

```sql
WITH ordered_data AS (
  SELECT m.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout) AS rn,
         LAG(timeinout) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout)
           AS previous_movement,
         LEAD(timeinout) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout)
           AS next_movement
  FROM   my_table m
),
grouped_data (
  emp_id,
  current_movement,
  flag,
  rn,
  previous_movement,
  next_movement,
  grp,
  check_status,
  first_movement
) AS (
  SELECT emp_id,
         timeinout,
         flag,
         rn,
         NULL,
         next_movement,
         1,
         'FIRST_CHECK',
         timeinout
  FROM   ordered_data
  WHERE  rn = 1
UNION ALL
  SELECT o.emp_id,
         o.timeinout AS current_movement,
         o.flag,
         o.rn,
         CASE
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         THEN o.previous_movement
         ELSE NULL
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         AND  (  o.next_movement >= g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
              OR o.next_movement IS NULL)
         THEN NULL
         ELSE o.next_movement
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         THEN g.grp
         ELSE g.grp + 1
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         AND  (  o.next_movement >= g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
              OR o.next_movement IS NULL)
         THEN 'LAST_CHECK'
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         THEN 'DURING_DAY'
         ELSE 'FIRST_CHECK'
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN o.timeinout < g.first_movement + INTERVAL '12' HOUR
         THEN g.first_movement
         ELSE o.timeinout
         END
  FROM   ordered_data o
         INNER JOIN grouped_data g
         ON (o.emp_id = g.emp_id AND o.rn = g.rn + 1)
)
SELECT emp_id,
       current_movement,
       flag,
       previous_movement,
       next_movement,
       (next_movement - current_movement) DAY TO SECOND AS diff,
       check_status
FROM   grouped_data
ORDER BY emp_id, current_movement
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae51165f71046fbdfc289ea69aed19fe)*

Comment: @MTO thank you, but I wondering,  we define the subquery of  "grouped_date" by using the" with " clause  but we use it in the same subquery of "grouped_data "

Comment: @M.Youssef Yes, it is a recursive sub-query factoring clause. If it did not refer to itself then it would not be recursive. A simple example is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e702546bef15b5dfb67a89bb4555ae3).

Comment: @MTO thank you very much. I think the recursive subquery factoring clause didn't work in the previous version (10g).

Comment: @M.Youssef I know, which was why I said "From Oracle 11gR2" at the start of the answer as that was the version when it was introduced. It won't help you on Oracle 10g but it may help someone else with a similar problem on a later version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PIPELINED` function:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_table_type AS OBJECT (
  emp_id            NUMBER,
  current_movement  DATE,
  flag              NUMBER,
  previous_movement DATE,
  next_movement     DATE,
  diff              INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  check_status      VARCHAR2(15)
);

CREATE TYPE my_table_tbltype AS TABLE OF my_table_type;
```

Then:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION parse_my_table RETURN my_table_tbltype PIPELINED
AS
  c_shift_length      CONSTANT INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND := INTERVAL '12' HOUR;
  v_emp_id            MY_TABLE.EMP_ID%TYPE;
  v_first_movement    MY_TABLE.TIMEINOUT%TYPE;
  v_previous_movement MY_TABLE.TIMEINOUT%TYPE;
  v_next_movement     MY_TABLE.TIMEINOUT%TYPE;
  v_check_status      VARCHAR2(15);
BEGIN
  FOR row IN (
    SELECT m.*,
           LAG(timeinout) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout)
             AS previous_movement,
           LEAD(timeinout) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY timeinout)
             AS next_movement
    FROM   my_table m
    ORDER BY m.emp_id, m.timeinout
  )
  LOOP
    IF v_emp_id IS NULL
    OR v_emp_id != row.emp_id
    OR row.timeinout >= v_first_movement + c_shift_length THEN
      v_emp_id            := row.emp_id;
      v_first_movement    := row.timeinout;
      v_previous_movement := NULL;
      v_next_movement     := row.next_movement;
      v_check_status      := 'FIRST_CHECK';
    ELSIF row.next_movement >= v_first_movement + c_shift_length 
    OR    row.next_movement IS NULL THEN
      v_previous_movement := row.previous_movement;
      v_next_movement     := NULL;
      v_check_status      := 'LAST_CHECK';
    ELSE
      v_previous_movement := row.previous_movement;
      v_next_movement     := row.next_movement;
      v_check_status      := 'DURING_DAY';
    END IF;
    PIPE ROW (
      my_table_type(
        row.emp_id,
        row.timeinout,
        row.flag,
        v_previous_movement,
        v_next_movement,
        (v_next_movement - row.timeinout) DAY TO SECOND,
        v_check_status
      )
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(parse_my_table());
```

Outputs:

> | EMP_ID | CURRENT_MOVEMENT | FLAG | PREVIOUS_MOVEMENT | NEXT_MOVEMENT | DIFF | CHECK_STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | 0 |  | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 | +00 08:34:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 | 1 | 2018-07-03T16:39:44 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:44 | 1 | 2018-07-04T01:14:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | 0 |  | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 | +00 08:52:48.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 | 1 | 2018-07-04T16:14:52 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:44 | 1 | 2018-07-05T01:07:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | 0 |  | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 | +00 08:30:40.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 | 1 | 2018-07-05T16:31:08 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | +00 00:00:04.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:52 | 1 | 2018-07-06T01:01:48 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 | 0 |  | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 | +00 07:49:56.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-03T16:27:36 | 0 | 2018-07-03T08:37:40 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | 0 |  | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | +00 04:21:32.000000 | FIRST_CHECK |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | 0 | 2018-07-04T08:37:04 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | +00 00:11:12.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 | 0 | 2018-07-04T12:58:36 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | +00 04:05:44.000000 | DURING_DAY |
> | 2 | 2018-07-04T17:15:32 | 0 | 2018-07-04T13:09:48 |  |  | LAST_CHECK |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fda1c9afb438d36854f872ab860f7051)*

Comment: @MTO thank you very much, It's working correctly.